Flutter Build Failed with an exeption
i try to run an old flutter project with the flutter run command but the build failed with a java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message).
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\AbdoulayeB\OneDrive\Bureau\flutter\jellyflut\android\app\build.gradle' line: 30

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 13s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             74,6s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

When i do ./gradlew --info i have this :
> Configure project :app
Evaluating project ':app' using build file 'C:\Users\AbdoulayeB\OneDrive\Bureau\flutter\jellyflut\android\app\build.gradle'.
Using Kotlin Gradle Plugin gradle70 variant
Caching disabled for Kotlin DSL script compilation (Project/ScriptPlugin/stage1) because:
  Build cache is disabled
Skipping Kotlin DSL script compilation (Project/ScriptPlugin/stage1) as it is up-to-date.
Could not execute [class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.statistics.KotlinBuildStatHandler.buildFinished]

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\AbdoulayeB\OneDrive\Bureau\flutter\jellyflut\android\app\build.gradle' line: 30

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s
4 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 2 up-to-date
Watched directory hierarchies: [C:\dev_mobile\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle]


Depending on the information that you provided , the easiest way to solve this problem is to
delete /android folder
and
run

flutter create .

Then run the project again.
If you don't want to delete /android folder please update you question adding build.gradle file so that I could know where is the problem .
